# jmesPath query lookup help. Is this query right?

Tags: jmespath

I have this JSON object:

```
{
            id: {
              name: "BBCommercialPropertyStructureFloodCoverage",
            },
            carrierData: null,
            link: [
              {
                key: "Location",
                select: {
                  key: "ARRAY_INDEX",
                  value: 0,
                },
              },
              {
                key: "structure",
                select: {
                  key: "ARRAY_INDEX",
                  value: 1,
                },
              },
              {
                key: "Coverage",
                select: {
                  key: "ARRAY_INDEX",
                  value: 0,
                },
              },
            ],
          },
```

I have several of these objects with different index values. For example, if I want to match on this `id/name: "BBCommercialPropertyStructureFloodCoverage"` and also that the location is value 0 and the structure is value 1, how do I do this using jmespath?

I have this so far:

`const floodCoverageQuery = [?id.name=='BBCommercialPropertyStructureFloodCoverage' && link[key=='Location' && select.value==0]] && link[key=="structure" && select.value==1]]`

Is this right?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the object tree you put in your answer is not true JSON. I've converted it, see below. Also, I suppose the object needs to be wrapped in a list (`[...]`) because you say *”I have several of these objects“*; and the jmespath query you have ”so far“ starts with `[?...`, which indicates you've got a list.

### answer

this should work, I've tested it on [jmespath.org](http://jmespath.org/):

`` [?id.name=='BBCommercialPropertyStructureFloodCoverage' && link[?key=='Location' && select.value==`0`] && link[?key=='structure' && select.value==`1`]] ``

### what was wrong with your solution?

Your original query was this:

> `[?id.name=='BBCommercialPropertyStructureFloodCoverage' && link[key=='Location' && select.value==0]] && link[key=="structure" && select.value==1]]`

This is what I had discovered:

- There are too many closing brackets (`]`). So `==0]] &&` should be `==0] &&` (one bracket less).
- You've mixed single and double quotes (`'` and `"`). Only single quotes are valid [raw string literals](http://jmespath.org/specification.html#raw-string-literals). (**Alteratively**, you could write `` ⁠`"string"`⁠ ``, which is equivalent to `'string'`.)
- Wrap integer values (0 and 1) inside backticks (`` ⁠`0`⁠ `` and `` ⁠`1`⁠ ``), see [literal expressions](http://jmespath.org/specification.html#literal-expressions).
- The inner brackets, where you check `key` and `select.value`, are [filter expressions](http://jmespath.org/specification.html#filter-expressions), so you need to wrap them inside `[?` and `]` instead of just `[...]`.

### FTR, the actual input as JSON

```
[
  {
    "id": {
      "name": "BBCommercialPropertyStructureFloodCoverage"
    },
    "carrierData": null,
    "link": [
      {
        "key": "Location",
        "select": {
          "key": "ARRAY_INDEX",
          "value": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "structure",
        "select": {
          "key": "ARRAY_INDEX",
          "value": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "Coverage",
        "select": {
          "key": "ARRAY_INDEX",
          "value": 0
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```